# How to select the parent element when child element checked?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, checked

I want to style my CheckBox. I wrote these code :

```
<div class="check-box-input">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

& I want to apply a style to parent div when input checked, I wrote this code but It doesn't work :

```
.check-box-input input:checked ~ .check-box-input {
    background-image: url('../Images/CheckBox.png');
}
```

Comment: Try to have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Comment: @FrankW. Thanks but I want to know how to do it like this ...

Comment: The is no parent selector in css

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes Thanks for your response ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no way in css to do this 
but instead you can use the css "+" selector which select element immediately after the selected element

check this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp